# c# WebService kills Singleton it owns

Tags: c#, wcf, singleton

I have a WebService, which owns a Singleton:

```
public class WebService
{
    private static Singleton _singleton = Singleton.Instance;

    public void DoSomeJob(object jobObj) {
        _singleton.QueueJob(jobObj);
    }
}
```

.. and the Singleton, which should be threadsafe.

```
public static Singleton Instance
{
    get
    {
        lock (_syncRoot)
        {
            if (_instance == null)
                _instance = new Singleton();

            return _instance;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I was going to achieve this way is, that every client calling my WebService gives its object to the same instance of the singleton. This singleton again, does not really do more than queueing the object and processing it when a timer ticks.

The problem I was facing (and still am), is that the Singleton is getting killed every time the WebService terminates. However, I am not sure if this is happening because the owner of the Singleton is being destructed or for some reason given by the app pool settings.
I have tried to make the app pool "always running" and "suspending" when idle, instead of "on demand" and "terminate" - no success :-/

Why is the Singleton getting killed off each time?  How can I keep the Singleton's instance alive between WebService executions?

Comment: Actually, my posting was starting with "Hi everybody", but it must have been cut somehow - pardon :)

Comment: Careful with those locks. Concurrent requests will get locked on that piece of code. I know it's what you intended, but concurrent requests should be independent and not stay in line waiting for its turn.

Comment: If thread safe collections is what you're looking for, give this a try: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.concurrent(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @mitch FYI, etiquette on Stackoverflow is to write your post in a FAQ style rather than a forum post or letter to other site users.  I edited your question slightly with that in mind.

Comment: @Mihai: Thank you for the link! However, could you point out why concurrent requests should not be waiting in line? I must confess that I do not really understand that.

Comment: @Brian: Also, thank you! I see the reason for the modifications you have made.

Comment: @mitch Because they won't be concurrent anymore, they'd instead get served one by one. And in web apps, concurrency is a must. Consider the case when, for some period of time, you get a massive number of requests. Instead of using the advantage of multi threading to serve them quickly, you instead line them up and serve one a time, increasing response times (and customer frustration). This situation is said to "not scale". Meaning that with the increase of work it does not perform as well.

Comment: @Mihai: Aaaah, I see, good explanation :-) However, I do not see a chance to create a thread safe singleton without that lock. In addition, I was thinking that the waiting time for each client is limited to the time it takes to get the instance of the singleton. And I also thought that this time is very little. Or am I wrong? And do I get you right that you would not make the singleton thread safe, but only its members?

Comment: @mitch Also, I see you are making the instance get accessor thread safe, but what about _singleton.QueueJob(jobObj); ? Is this implemented in a thread safe manner? This is imperative to be, because multiple threads will call that method in a concurrent manner.

Comment: @mitch If concurrent queues is what you need, have a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396 I suggest you use this instead of your home baked implementation. It will be a heck of a lot more robust.

Comment: @Mihai: Okay, thanks again! I understand what you are saying and I guess you are right. I will deal with the topics discussed on the linked pages :)

Comment: @mitch Anytime, mate!

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the Singleton getting killed off each time?

You need to understand about how WCF manages service [instancing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand why this is. By default WCF will create a new service instance per client over a [session-enabled binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730879(v=vs.110).aspx), or per call if no session is supported.

This means that the service instance which is dispached to handle a client call will load an instance of your singleton into memory. However, when either the the client session, or individual call (where no session is supported) has finished, the instance is unloaded, which means your singleton will also get unloded.

> How can I keep the Singleton's instance alive between WebService
>   executions?

There are two ways to do this:

1. Get rid of your singleton. Use a backing data store to maintain your state across mutliple clients calls.
2. Use a singleton service instance, by setting `InstanceContextMode=InstanceContxtMode.Single` in your service implementation declaration.

Of the two options I would go with option 1. This is because singleton service instances are generally an anti-pattern because they [do not scale](https://www.google.co.uk/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=wcf%20singleton%20scalability), and should only be used when there is no alternative.

> ....considered to implement the queueing functionality to an external
>   component, e.g. a windows service, but for the purpose of simplicity
>   and reduced complexity I would like to implement that within the
>   WebService

OK, right there is where I think the source of your problem is. There is a common belief around ditributed systems, which can be stated as the following:

- Simple = fewer components, and
- Complex = more components

I would modify that belief to:

- Simple = simple components, and
- Complex = complex components

In my opinion your decision to embed your timer/queueing requirement into your web service automatically makes your component complex.

I think breaking out the component which reads from the queue into another component is exactly what you need to do!

If this is daunting to you, then I would very strongly recommend using [topshelf](https://github.com/Topshelf/Topshelf) to manage your windows service, which is a free framework which makes the creation and deployment of services very simple.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer, Tom! Regarding your choice, I totally agree with you. Although I didn't know option 2 is a known "anti-pattern", I had decided against that solution before I have written my posting. In my oppinion, there is no reason to keep an instance of the service alive all the time. Doing so was a quick solution, but also a dirty one. However, option 1 does not seem to be a valid solution, neither, since the singleton is not used for sharing data across different request. The singleton should be used to keep a timer running ..

Comment: @mitch - Hmm I see. So can you explain again what this timer is for?

Comment: Sure. Every service client should give an object to the singleton. The singleton should add this object to a queue. On every tick of the mentioned timer, the first x objects of that queue should be processed. I have also considered to implement the queueing functionality to an external component, e.g. a windows service, but for the purpose of simplicity and reduced complexity I would like to implement that within the WebService.

Comment: I see your point, Tom, and I agree up to a certain point. My basic idea was, that queueing and processing the objects is only relevant as long as the web service is running. This is why I was going to implement that queueing functionality directly as a part of this web service. Outsourcing that functionality to an external component would also mean, that the timer was running even if the web service is not even running or if there is no object to process. To avoid that, I would have to make both components comuincate with each other, and so on .. comment is getting too long. Thanks a lot! :-)

Comment: @mitch - *queueing and processing the objects is only relevant as long as the web service is running* - how do you define "relevant"? I do not understand your reasoning here. When the web service is not running then there will be no activity on the queueing and processing component.